# Git::Repository: use of uninitialized value $git_dir

Tags: git, perl, cpan

I've just had my sysadmin install `Git::Repository` on a solaris-server for me. I wrote a little test-script, to check if the basic functionality of the module is working and came across this error:

```
Use of uninitialized value $git_dir in -d at /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.12.3/Git/Repository.pm line 97.
Use of uninitialized value $git_dir in concatenation (.) or string at /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.12.3/Git/Repository.pm line 97.
directory not found:  at ./list_commits.pl line 28
```

My code:

```
  1 #!/usr/local/bin/perl -w
  2 use strict;
  3
  4 use Git::Repository;
  5 use Data::Dumper;
  6 my $git_path = '~/gitstuff/repo/sandbox/.git';
  7 my $repo = Git::Repository->new(
  8         work_tree => $git_path
  9 );
 10 die Dumper $repo;
```

I just don't get it, why the module tells me, that $git_dir is undefined, when it's clearly there in the arguments. And in addition, the directory definitely exists.

```
bash-3.2$ pwd
~/gitstuff/repo/sandbox/.git
```

Any hints?

Comment: drop `-w` switch and `use warnings;` instead. `-w` forces system wide warnings.

Comment: Perl doesn't know that "~" means home directory.

Comment: @squiguy You're right. Please post your comment as an answer, so I can accept it :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
my $git_path = '~/gitstuff/repo/sandbox/.git';
```

must be a valid path, and `~` should be replaced by

```
my $git_path = $ENV{HOME} . '/gitstuff/repo/sandbox/.git';
```